# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ON Database Query

Tags: mysql, node.js

am trying to work with Node and Mysql on my Ec2 instance but i keep encountering error when trying to connect with the Database.

```
var _mysql = require('mysql');

var MYSQL_USER = 'root';
var MYSQL_PASS = '**********';
var DATABASE = 'adas';
var TABLE = 'ep';

var mysql = _mysql.createClient({
user: MYSQL_USER,
password: MYSQL_PASS,
});

mysql.query('use' + DATABASE, function(err) {
if (err) {
throw err;
}
});
```

And i keep getting the following Error

node.js:201
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:614:11)
at Object.afterConnect as oncomplete

Any idea what might be wrong?
Your Assistance would be appreciated.

**Update**

Fixed. Mysql Server crashed along the way and this was not known. Once i restarted the MySQL server, everything works fine.

Comment: connection refused maybe ? have a look if mysql is allowing connections, you allso have a missing white space on you're first query .

Comment: I ran a similar code on my local machine and it works...So i know the problem is not with Node, but with Ec2. Do i need to have any specific port opened from the AWS console? That should not be the case since as it is not an inbound connection. Your insight would be appreciated